# Connect to SQL DB via Textbox

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

So I am trying to use a connection string that is pasted into a textbox to connect to a db when the connect button is clicked. I have the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace SQLTool
{
    public partial class SQLTool : Form
    {
        public SQLTool()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }
        public static SqlConnection myConnection = null;

        public void Connection()
        {
            myConnection = new SqlConnection(DBConnectionBox.Text);
            //myConnection.Open();
        }


        private void DBConnectBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(DBConnectionBox.Text.ToString());
            myConnection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=ServerName;" + "Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;" + "User ID=UserName;" + "Password=Password";
            myConnection.Open();

            if (myConnection !=null && myConnection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("SUCCESS!!");
            }


        }




    }
}
```

I have added a picture of my form. The combobox I will be adding data from the db I connect to. So any help on that would be appreciated as well.
[Form Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSrEi.png)

Maybe someone can point me into the right direction. The if statement was just for testing if I was connecting to the db. This is my first time trying something like this so I am a bit lost. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace SQLTool
{
    public partial class SQLTool : Form
    {
        public SQLTool()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }
        public static SqlConnection myConnection = null;




        private void DBConnectBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            try
            {
                var myConnection = new SqlConnection(DBConnectionBox.Text);
                myConnection.Open();
                if (myConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    var sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Menu", myConnection);
                    var sqlReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

                    while (sqlReader.Read())
                        ClientComboBox.Items.Add(sqlReader["Name"].ToString());

                    //MessageBox.Show("SUCCESS!!");


                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"Failed to connect. Message {ex.Message}");
            }


        }


    }
}
```

The only thing left to do is to populate the datagridview with a SQL Query that is ran depending on what I pick in the combobox.

Ok guys, new problem:

```
private void ClientComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            var myConnection = new SqlConnection(DBConnectionBox.Text);
            myConnection.Open();
            if  (myConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                var Cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Menu WHERE Name ='" + ClientComboBox.Text + "';");
                var Reader = Cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while(Reader.Read())
                {
                    SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdap = new SqlDataAdapter(Cmd);

                    DataSet dtRecord = new DataSet();
                    sqlDataAdap.Fill(dtRecord);
                    ClientInfoDGV.DataSource = dtRecord;

                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

When I click on a combobox item something is populated in the datagridview (ClientInfoDGV). It goes straight to the catch.

Comment: Comment out that line `myConnection.ConnectionString ...` , since `ConnectionString`  Property is already initialized via `SqlConnection` constructor. Also check for `myConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open`.

Comment: Do you get an error when you run the porgram?

Comment: No I don't get an error. I don't get anything when I copy the connection string in the textbox.

Comment: Remember to call `myConnection.Close();` too as soon as you are finished.

Or you can use using{} block.

I presume you are not getting because you are assigning the connectionstring straight after you get the values from the text box, which you don't need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not reinitialize `ConnectionString` property of `myConnection` object, since it is already initialized.

Also notice that you should check for `myConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open` in order to determine where connection is opened or not.

You can try following

```
public static SqlConnection myConnection = null;
private void DBConnectBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
    var myConnection = new SqlConnection(DBConnectionBox.Text);
    myConnection.Open();
    if (myConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
      MessageBox.Show("SUCCESS!!");
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  { MessageBox.Show($"Failed to connect. Message {ex.Message}"); }
}
```

Comment: @Tim Oh, i mentioned it in comments but posted a code with same mistake. Thanks Tim.

Comment: @JamesRobertSingleton

That's to do with your button click not firing the method then. How did it work before? None of this new code should affect that.

Comment: Could I add a SqlCommand inside that try block and then use that to populate a combobox? Or would I need to do that in a separate statement?

Comment: @MartinMazzaDawson yea I realized I didn't double click on the button and that I just wrote it out. Just had to connect it. Oops.

Comment: @JamesRobertSingleton Yes, you can create `SqlCommand` inside `if` statement body.

Comment: So I added SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand ("Select * From Menu");

Then I put ClientComboBox.Items.Add(command); but nothing populates that comboBox.

I think I might have to do something in properties but I am not sure. I have never populated a combobox from a sql db before.

Comment: @JamesRobertSingleton You can try this. `var sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Menu", myConnection);
      var sqlReader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
      while (sqlReader.Read())
        ClientComboBox.Items.Add(sqlReader["ColumnName"].ToString());` Notice that you should replace `ColumnName` with your desired column name.

Comment: @tchelidze so the sqlReader actually executes the sqlCommand? Just trying to learn as well instead of just asking questions.

Comment: @JamesRobertSingleton `SqlReader` object is returned from `ExecuteReader` method, In order to use that object (`SqlReader`) for reading data returned by query.

Comment: @tchelidze awesome and thank you very much. See my update above.

Comment: @JamesRobertSingleton glad if helped.

Comment: @tchelidze one more question. So I was messing around and clicked a couple times on the connect button and it populated my combobox that many times. Is there a way to not populate the combobox more than once even if you click the button more than once?

Comment: @JamesRobertSingleton Sure, just above `while(Reader.Read())` line you can if `combobox` items contain any element, if so, do not add data to it. Or you can `Clear` `combobox.Items` that will ensure no dublicate items is populated in combobox.

Comment: @tchelidze I did the clear, it came to me after I asked this.

Comment: @JamesRobertSingleton Good job.